# When a class is instantiated in java using the new keyword, does every super class in the hierarchy get Instantiated ?

Tags: java, class, constructor

For Example consider three classes A,B and C. B extends A and C extends B.
 Now class C has all the accessible methods and fields of B.

When an instance of C is created as -----  C c = new C(), Heap area is 
    allocated for the instance fields in 'C' (Does it includes properties of 'A' 
    and 'B' also ?). When the super class constructor is called, a new object of
    super class must be created. Where is the reference to this object stored ?

How is the class hierarchy managed when a class object is instantiated ?

Comment: There are not _separate_ objects.  The `C` object _is also_ a `B` and _is also_ an `A`.  There is only one reference, to only one object.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: actually C has all methods and fields of B and A; not only he accessible ones, despite the code of C not necessarely has access to all of them. As Louis wrote, C is an (extension) of B and A, like a car is also a vehicle which is an object.

Comment: Thanks for that. Then where are the private fields of super class stored. I hope they cannot be stored in the same object as they are not accessible.

Comment: Also in case of hidden fields - how can two fields with the same be stored in the same object ?

Comment: Private fields and methods are not accessible from the object. If you have same named methods, then you will need to use @override and then it will call the overridden method.

Comment: Thanks for that Louis Wasserman.                                                              
 My other questions are:                                                                                 1.Then where are the private fields of super class stored. I hope they cannot be stored in the same object as they are not accessible ?                                                 2.Also in case of hidden fields - how can two fields with the same be stored in the same object ?

Answer (score 1):

The (one) new instance will have heap space allocated for the fields of all three classes. Calling super-class constructors does not create new instances, it only initializes fields.